Harsh alpha edge when combining clips in Video Editing
I'm new to Blender and I'm stumbling on a surely simple problem.
I want to use the Video Editing module to combine the rendered .exr image sequence of an animated layer over a background. Using Cycles. If I render my object (the good old donut) over its background together, it blends in nicely (B), but if I render the object on its own with alpha and then combine it (Alpha Over) using the Video Editing Sequencer, I'm getting this harsh edge (A).

This it the timeline. Very simple.

My donut Compositing tab is simple enough. It must have something to do with a small group of nodes to make the donut bloom a bit.
I have tried with the Alpha Convert node at the end, and while it makes the edge a bit better, it also removes the bloom. Maybe there is another tick or a different node?


Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanks.
